# How to use non-clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

I have general question about non-clustered index working suppose I have 4 non clustered index on my table and I want to know that which non-clustered index is calling form these 4 indexes and is there ant way to use a specific index from these 4 indexes.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The ANSI SQL specification doesn't cover indexes.)

Comment: I am using ms sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running your query, hit cntr-M, or select "Include Actual Execution Plan" from the Query menu of SQL Server Management studio.  When the query completes, click on the "execution plan" tab of the results window.  Scroll around until you find where the plan reads from table in question, and it will tell which index was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can force SELECT query to use particular index using hint as below:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM Table_Name WITH(INDEX(Index_Name))
```

Say for table 'Tab_test' four non clustered indexes have been defined like Idx_1,Idx_2,Idx_3 and Idx_4. Now you want to SELECT query to use Idx_3 then below query will force SELECT statement to use Idx_3:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM Tab_test WITH(INDEX(Idx_3))
```

Comment: okay that's fine. Now how can I figure out which index is using if I didn't mention any index.If i have this simple query 
"SELECT <columns> FROM Table_Name"
 Here is two questions arise that whether any index from  Idx_1,Idx_2,Idx_3 and Idx_4 will be used or not. If any index used how can I figure out which will be used.

Comment: Thanks CBS for 1 problem